# Asp.net MVC Force update of javascript file in a bundle

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

When I'm developing a web page, I usually include a parameter after the .js reference every time I changed it, to force the browser to get the new version and prevent it to keep with the old one.

For instance, if my reference is like this:

```
<script src="myfile.js" />
```

The browser will cache the javascript file, and when I publish a new one, it won't get, keeping the old one. So I change the reference to:

```
<script src="myfile.js?ver=2" />
```

Since the browser index the cache by URL, it will think it is a different file and get it again.

But how can I do that if my javascript is in an asp.net bundle?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/global").Include(
               "~/Scripts/my/global.js"));
```

I tried the below code but didn't work. How can I force the browser to download the script again in this case?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/global").Include(
               "~/Scripts/my/global.js?ver=2",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I can't stand the bundler, and have always managed my scripts manually.
So this answer might not be exactly what you're looking for, but will help address having to manually update the `?ver=#` every time.

Create a class, perhaps `FileVersionRepo` that on application start (inside `Global.asax`) will contain a `private static Dictionary<string,string>` where the key is a file name, and the value is the `FileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToFileTime().ToString()` value. This will read the file's lastWriteTime only once when the App Pool restarts, or app is published.

This is also handy for CSS files.

```
public static class FileVersionRepo {
    private static Object _lock = new Object();
    private static Dictionary<string,string> fileVals = new Dictionary<string,string>();

    public string GetVal(string key) { return fileVals[key]; }
    public string SetVal(string key, string path) {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
                FileWriteTimes[key] = fileInfo.LastWriteTime.ToFileTime().ToString();
            else
                return;// maybe throw exception here?
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your Global.asax.cs:

```
protected virtual void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    FileVersionRepo.SetVal("global.js", "path/global.js");
}
```

Then in your View:

```
using FileVersionRepo;

<script src="global.js?ver=@FileVersionRepo.GetVal("global.js")"><script>
```

Answer (score -1):

The default MVC project create a jquery bundle like the below

I think your bundle should be like this:

```
       bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/global").Include(
           "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
```

Hope that helps!